# How to align text, structures, and arrows in chemfig package

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

Any idea how to align the names of structures to the same height. The arrow and the plus signs, and the chemical structures, too.

I tried to align them with `\chemnameinit`, but does not work.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\scalebox{.6}{
\chemnameinit{\chemfig{[:210]O*3(-(-R|^1)-(-R|^2)-)}}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{R|^1-=-R|^2}}{Alqueno}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2O_2}}{Peróxido\\de hidrógeno}
\arrow{->[Base][Disolvente]}[0,2]
\chemname{\chemfig{[:210]O*3(-(-R|^1)-(-R|^2)-)}}{Epóxido}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Agua}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}
}
\caption{Reacción de epoxidación. Oxidación de un alqueno en presencia de un peróxido de hidrógeno y una base orgánica.}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to go about doing it, but you can specify the anchor points used for the middle arrow, then manually shift the `epxido` molecule upwards with a `yshift`. I've marked out the changes in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \scalebox{.6}{
    \chemnameinit{\chemfig{[:210]O*3(-(-R|^1)-(-R|^2)-)}}
    %\schemedebug{true} % Activate to see anchor points
    \schemestart
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{R^1-=-R^2}
        }{Alqueno}
    \+
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{H_2O_2}
        }{Peróxido\\de hidrógeno}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west) % <--------
        {->[Base][Disolvente]}[0,2] 
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig[yshift=2em]{[:210]O*3(-(-R|^1)-(-R|^2)-)} % <--------
        }{Epóxido}
    \+
    \chemname{%
        \chemfig{H_2O}
        }{Agua}
    \schemestop
    \chemnameinit{}
    }
    \caption{Reacción de epoxidación. Oxidación de un alqueno en presencia de un peróxido de hidrógeno y una base orgánica.}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: reaction scheme]

**Addendum**

You can have a look at the anchor points and how `chemfig` groups the molecules together using `\schemedebug{true}` placed before `\schemestart` (Uncomment it in the above code to see what I mean). It's useful when trying to align the arrows, +, and molecules in a reaction scheme.

[image: with debug on]